# Acts 2:38 vs Matthew 28:20- "In" vs "On" - By what nuance of meaning would Jesus use εἰς (eis) in Matthew while Peter would use ἐπί (epi) in Acts

Tags: matthew, jesus, acts, word-choice, baptism

By what nuance of meaning, in context, would Jesus use εἰς (eis) in Matthew and while Peter would use ἐπί (epi) in Acts?

In Matthew 28:19,
Jesus instructs his disciples regarding the nations, that they are to be *"...baptizing them **in (εἰς - eis)** the name of the Father and of the Son and of the Holy Spirit"*

In Acts 2:38,
Peter instructs the Jews to *"...be baptized every one of you **in (ἐπί - epi)** the name of Jesus Christ..."*

These two words, **ἐπί (epi)** and **εἰς (eis)**, are both translated as *'in'* though they seem possess meanings distinct from each other:

Strong's Concordance Definition for **ἐπί (epi)**:

> on, upon

vs
Strong's Concordance Definition for **εἰς (eis)**:

> to or into (indicating the point reached or entered, of place, time, purpose, result)

Comment: Those baptising, (Matthew 28:19) baptise unto (_eis_). Those who _are_ baptised (Acts 2:38) are baptised in (or within _epi_). The baptisers are external to the experience. The baptisees are _within_ the experience. I see no contradiction. –

Comment: Was any of this helpful?

Answer (score 0):

This question has been much debated and will not be settled here.  So, let me confine my answer to the Biblical data concerning prepositions before the Greek word ὄνομα (onoma = "name").

**διὰ [τὸ] ὄνομά = through/because of/on account of the name**

- Matt 10:22 - And you will be hated by all **on account of the name** of Me; but the one having endured to the end, he will be saved.
- Mark 13:13 - And you will be hated by all **on account of the name** of Me; but the one having endured to the end, he will be saved.
- Luke 21:17 - And you will be hated by all **because of the name** of Me.
- John 15:21 - But they will do all these things against you **on account of the name** of Me, because they have not known the One having sent Me.

**εἰς [τὸ] ὄνομα = in the name**

- Matt 10:41 - The one receiving a prophet **in the name** of a prophet will receive the reward of a prophet, and the one receiving a righteous man **in the name** of a righteous man will receive the reward of a righteous man.
- Matt 10:41 - And whoever shall give to drink to one of these little ones only a cup of cold water **in the name** of a disciple, truly I say to you, he shall certainly not lose his reward."
- Matt 28:19 - Therefore having gone, disciple all the nations, baptizing them **in the name** of the Father, and of the Son, and of the Holy Spirit
- John 1:12 - But as many as received Him, He gave to them authority to be children of God--to those believing **in the name** of Him
- John 2:23 - And when He was in Jerusalem in the Passover, in the Feast, many believed **in the name** of Him, beholding His signs that He was doing.
- John 3:18 - The one believing in Him is not judged, but the one not believing already has been judged, because he has not believed **in the name** of the only begotten Son of God.

**ἐπὶ τῷ ὀνόματί = in/on/upon/unto the name**

- Matt 18:5 - And whoever shall receive one such little child **in the name** of Me, receives Me.
- Matt 18:20 - For where two or three are gathered together **unto My name**, there am I in their midst."
- Matt 24:45 - For many will come **in the name** of Me, saying, 'I am the Christ,' and they will mislead many.
- Mark 9:37 - "Whoever shall receive one of such little children **in the name** of Me, receives Me; and whoever shall receive Me, does not receive Me, but the One having sent Me."
- Mark 9:39 - And Jesus said, "Do not forbid him. For there is no one who will do a work of power **in [the] name** of Me, and will be able readily to speak evil of Me.
- Mark 13:6 - Many will come **in the name** of Me, saying, 'I am He,' and they will mislead many.
- Luke 1:59 - And it came to pass on the eighth day, they came to circumcise the child, and were calling it **after the name** of his father, Zechariah.
- Luke 9:48 - and He said to them, "Whoever shall receive this child **in the name** of Me, receives Me; and whoever shall receive Me, receives the One having sent Me. For the one being least among you all, he shall be great."
- Luke 21:8 - And He said, "Take heed, lest you be led astray; for many will come **in the name** of Me, saying, 'I am He,' and 'The time is drawn near.' Do not go after them.
- Luke 24:47 - and repentance and forgiveness of sins to be proclaimed **in the name** of Him to all nations, having begun from Jerusalem.
- Acts 2:38 - And Peter says to them, "Repent and be baptized, every one of you, **in the name** of Jesus Christ for the forgiveness of your sins, and you will receive the gift of the Holy Spirit.
- Acts 4:17 - But that it might not spread further on among the people, let us warn them to speak no longer to no-one **in the name** of this [man]."
- Acts 4:18 - And having called them, they commanded them not to speak nor to teach at all **in the name** of Jesus.

**ἐν [τῷ] ὀνόματί = in/on the name**

- Matt 21:9 - And the crowds going before Him and those following were crying out, saying: "Hosanna to the Son of David!" "Blessed is the One coming **in the name** of the Lord!" "Hosanna in the highest!"
- Mark 9:38 - John answered Him, "Teacher, we saw someone who does not follow us casting out demons **in the name** of You, and we were forbidding him, because he was not following us."
- Mark 9:41 - For whoever might give you to drink a cup of water because you are Christ's **in name**, truly I say to you, that he shall certainly not lose his reward.
- Mark 11:9 - And those going before and those following were crying out: "Hosanna!" "Blessed is the One coming **in the name** of the Lord!"
- Mark 16:17 - And these signs will accompany those having believed: **In the name** of Me they will cast out demons; they will speak with new tongues;
- Luke 9:49 - And John answering said, "Master, we saw someone casting out demons **in the name** of You, and we were forbidding him, because he does not follow with us."
- Luke 10:17 - And the seventy-two returned with joy, saying, "Lord, even the demons are subject to us **through the name** of You."
- Luke 13:35 - Behold, your house is left to you. And I say to you, you shall not see Me until the time comes when you say, 'Blessed is the One coming **in the name** of the Lord.'"
- Luke 19:38 - saying: "Blessed is the King who comes **in [the] name** of the Lord!" "Peace in heaven and glory in the highest!"
- John 5:43 - I have come **in the name** of the Father of Me, and you do not receive Me; if another should come **in the name** of his-own, you will receive him.
- John 10:25 - Jesus answered them, "I told you, and you do not believe. The works that I do **in the name** of Father of Me, these bear witness concerning Me.
- John 12:13 - took the branches of the palm trees and went out to meet Him, and were shouting: "Hosanna!" "Blessed is the One coming **in [the] name** of the Lord!" "And the King of Israel!"
- John 14:13 - And whatever you might ask **in the name** of Me, this I will do, so that the Father may be glorified in the Son.
- John 14:14 - If you ask Me anything **in the name** of Me, I will do it.
- John 14:26 - But the Helper, the Holy Spirit, whom the Father will send **in the name** of me, He will teach you all things and will bring to your remembrance all things that I have said to you.
- John 15:16 - You did not chose Me, but I chose you and appointed you, that you should go and you should bear fruit, and your fruit should remain, so that whatever you might ask the Father **in the name** of Me, He may give you.
- John 16:23 - And in that day, you will ask of Me nothing. Truly, truly, I say to you, whatever you may ask the Father **in the name** of Me, He will give you.
- John 16:24 - Until now you have asked nothing **in the name** of Me. Ask and you will receive, that your joy may be full.
- John 16:26 - In that day you will ask **in the name** of Me, and I do not say to you that I will implore the Father for you.
- John 17:11 - And I am no longer in the world, and yet they are themselves in the world, and I am coming to You. Holy Father, keep them **in the name** of You, which You have given Me, that they may be one as we are.
- John 17:12 - When I was with them, I was keeping them **in the name** of You, which You have given Me. And I guarded them, and none of them has perished, except the son of destruction, that the Scripture might be fulfilled.
- John 20:31 - But these are written so that you may believe that Jesus is the Christ, the Son of God, and that by believing you may have life **in the name** of Him.
- Acts 3:6 - But Peter said, "Silver and gold, to me there is none; but what I have, this I give to you: **In the name** of Jesus Christ of Nazareth, rise up and walk!"
- Acts 4:10 - let it be known to all of you, and to all the people of Israel, that **in the name** of Jesus Christ of Nazareth--whom you crucified, whom God raised out from the dead--in Him this man stands before you sound.

From this survey we observe the following facts:

- Several of these prepositions appear (in this context) to be used interchangeably such as ἐν vs ἐπὶ (Mark 9:37, 38, 39, 41); see also Luke 9:48 vs Luke 9:49; and Acts 4:10 vs $;17, 18.
- The prepositions ἐπὶ and εἰς are sometimes used interchangeably (as the OP has observed) in places like Matt 28:19 and Acts 2:28.
- Further, the meanings of these prepositions overlap considerably and that is why they are often used interchangeably.

In a few places, a preposition is completely absent and the article acts in its place such as:

- Acts 2:21 - And it shall be that everyone who shall call **upon the name** of the Lord will be saved.'
- Acts 3:16 - And on the faith **in His name**, this man whom you see and know, His name has strengthened; and the faith which is through Him has given to him this complete soundness before all of you.

Many have tried to make very fine distinctions between the use of these prepositions such as, "on the subject of" vs "in the authority/power of", etc.  However, it appears that the NT writers at times almost deliberately blurred these differences (if any really exist).  Thus all that one might conclude is that invoking the name of God, the Father or Jesus simply means to act on/by their authority and teaching.

[BDAG has an extended article about this subject of the "the name" under ὄνομά which I have summarized in the brief statement above.]

Comment: What name will one use to invoke the name of God?

Comment: @AlexBalilo - nice try but I will not bite except to quote what the NT clearly says: "that at the name of **Jesus** every knee should bow, in the heavens and on earth and under the earth," Phil 2:10.

Comment: Why not? Part of your answer says "one might conclude is that invoking the name of God,,"  So this God you speak of has a name,. Is it because you do not want to his name known, contrary to what Jesus said? By the way, this  God that you refuse to name is the God that gave Jesus the name that is above every other name. Philippians 2:9. Nice try.

Comment: @AlexBalilo this is not an appropriate use of Comments.

Answer (score -1):

The hypothesis that the Gospel of Matthew was written in Hebrew is pertinent to the case of prepositions, as Greek is a geometric language. In the case of the Gospel of Matthew, the fact that there is a less rigorous translation and with fewer resources, such as the number of witnesses, weighs heavily.

However, the εἰς τὸ ὄνομα (Acts 8:16  and Acts 19:5 NAS27) verses are in compatibility with Matthew 28:20, so does this indeed suggest a different understanding for the use of a different preposition? Does the author of Atos de Apostolos interchange prepositions without rigor in other passages of the book?

The verses of Matthew 28:19; João. 3:18; chiefly Acts 8:16; 19:5 and even 1 John 5:13 support the baptizing of waters, while the construction using ἐπί in Acts 2:38 refers to receiving the gift (dorea) of the holy spirit, referring/recalling the **authorization** given by Jesus Christ as verified in these verses: Mattews 18:5; 24:5; Mark. 9:37, 39; 13:6; Luke. 1:59; 9:48; 21:8; 24:47; Acts 4:17-18; 5:28, 40.

> And having come near, Jesus spake to them, saying, 'Given to me was all **authority** in heaven and on earth; having gone, then, disciple all the nations, (baptizing them -- to the name of the Father, and of the Son, and of the Holy Spirit (Matt. 28:18-19 YLT)